# how to get the userinfo using mod_auth_cas from session?

Tags: python, django, apache, cas, mod-auth

I use `mod_auth_cas` as the cas client,and here is my conf file in http.conf of apache:

```
CASDebug On
CASValidateServer Off
CASCookiePath /var/cache/apache2/mod_auth_cas/
CASLoginURL https://example/cas/login
CASValidateURL https://example/cas/serviceValidate
<Location /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/>
Authtype CAS
require valid-user
</Location>
```

And I used django, I can get user name by using `request.META['REMOTE_USER']`,But I can not get other informations about user,such as,the email, address which is already configured in the cas server and they should be got. When I use `request.session.keys()`, it is empty. Did anyone knows the reason? Is my conf file wrong? thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with "samlValidate" for the CASValidateURL option :

```
CASValidateURL https://example/cas/samlValidate
```